# xslt get immediate next sibling

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CaseResponse xmlns="http://webservices.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CaseResult>
        <Response xmlns="">
            <Case>
              <CaseID>1441</CaseID>
              <Status>open</Status>
              <CreationDate>03/10/2023</CreationDate>
              <Task>
                <TaskID>2826</TaskID>
                <Status>open</Status>
                <TaskData>
                    <Key>Issue</Key>
                    <Value>some issue</Value>
                    <Key>Type</Key>
                    <Value>some type</Value>
                    <Key>JobType</Key>
                    <Value>xyz</Value>
                </TaskData>
              </Task>
              <Task>
                <TaskID>2827</TaskID>
                <Status>open</Status>
                <TaskData/>
              </Task>
            </Case>
        </Response>
    </CaseResult>
 </CaseResponse>
```

and I have the following xslt to transform the data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dfor="http://myapi.com/dforms"
 exclude-result-prefixes="dfor">


<xsl:template match="/">
<dfor:form-data>
    <dfor:field>
        <dfor:name>cases</dfor:name>
        <dfor:children>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <xsl:for-each select="//Case">
                <dfor:child>
                    <dfor:field>
                        <dfor:name>CaseID</dfor:name>
                        <dfor:value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CaseID"/>
                        </dfor:value>
                    </dfor:field>
                    <dfor:field>
                        <dfor:name>Status</dfor:name>
                        <dfor:value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Status"/>
                        </dfor:value>
                    </dfor:field>
                
                    <dfor:field>
                        <dfor:name>Type</dfor:name>
                        <dfor:value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Task/TaskData[Key='Type']/following-sibling::Value[1]"/>
                        </dfor:value>
                    </dfor:field>
                </dfor:child>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dfor:children>
    </dfor:field>
</dfor:form-data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to get the `type` value from the TaskData which are structured as key value pairs. So in the above example the value of `type` is `some type`. I tried the following but I'm getting empty results.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Task/TaskData[Key='Type']/following-sibling::Value[1]"/>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I've already provided all that.

Comment: ##3,4 are missing

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Task/TaskData[Key='Type']/following-sibling::Value[1]"/>
```

looks for the following sibling of `TaskData`, not of `Key`. It should be instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Task/TaskData/Key[.='Type']/following-sibling::Value[1]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:web="http://webservices.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="web">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/web:CaseResponse">
    <root>
       <xsl:for-each select="//TaskData/Key">
            <field>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </name>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Value[1]"/>
                </value>
            </field>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the posted input XML, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <field>
      <name>Issue</name>
      <value>some issue</value>
   </field>
   <field>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>some type</value>
   </field>
   <field>
      <name>JobType</name>
      <value>xyz</value>
   </field>
</root>
```